# Error when running pod install on adding Razorpay_flutter 1.1.2 in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, razorpay

I am trying to add razorpay_flutter 1.1.2 in my project but getting pod install error during build.

When I remove razorpay_flutter from pubspec my project build successful. I tried downgrading the version and did all the troubleshoot mentioned by publisher, but nothing works.

This is my error.

````
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A razorpay_flutter
  - Flutter
  - device_info

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `razorpay_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/razorpay_flutter/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_9_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/Users/kathirva/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/pod install --verbose
```


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.8.4
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 3.0.6
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G4015)
       Xcode : 10.1 (10B61)
         Git : git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib
Repositories : master - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 81697d55b6ebe7d58eae307fa584ff0b63da639c
               trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```
````

### Error

````
```
ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/Users/kathirva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:283:in `split'

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0

Error running pod install
````

Answer (score -1):

could you try to run this

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

before pod install?

And what OS do you use?